# How can I open a modal from a modal template?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-click

I'm new on Angular JS + Bootstrap 3 and I'm trying to do something for maps. the thing is that I need to open a modal, and then from a button of that modal open another modal.

This is the external html:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h1>Editor<h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" >
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="treureModalEdit()" data-dismiss="modal">Afegir Punt</button>
</div>`
```

Here is my example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zx68EQ?p=info

If something does not load is because libraries, but i only need help where the button 'Posa Marcador!' is.

Some code is in catalan, sorry if that discourages you to help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323500/open-modal-inside-a-modal. It uses [Angular-Bootstrap $modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) instead of $dialog but does exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect with your browser's developer tools the first modal that you open you will see that the markup for this modal is appended to the end of your HTML `body`, which means that the modal is not nested in your `<div ng-controller="DialogDemoCtrl">`. This in turn means that the modal does not have a controller of its own, and therefore cannot "understand" the `ng-click="treureModalEdit()"` you have defined for your button.

In order to fix this problem you should create a second controller and use it for your modal. The `treureModalEdit()` would then be placed into that second controller.

A few other comments I have on your code:

1. You use things like `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit"`, however this is how you would be opening your modal if you did not have an Angular application. In your Angular application what you actually use is the `ng-click="func()"` you have put on the button. You can therefore clean all this dead code from your HTML (data attributes and modal template).
2. If you are new to Angular I would suggest using a newer version in order to avoid any problems which might be fixed in newer versions. You can use the latest version (1.4.0) or a 1.2.x version is you need to support IE8 (which is not officially supported since Angular version 1.3.x.

Comment: Everything you say makes sense. I'm going to try that, correct the errors/dead-code and post a response. Thanks a lot.